# Braintree PayPal integration Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, paypal, braintree

I am developing a mobile app using Xamarin Forms where I need to integrate payment Gateway. Previously I was using [PayPal Forms](https://github.com/AlejandroRuiz/PayPal.Forms) for inApp payment and now this plugin is deprecated with no more support with IOS App Crashing on Start if I install this plugin and deploy the app.

Publisher of this plugin suggested to use Braintree to do PayPal payment. So I came across this [Braintree Xamarin Forms integration](http://www.xamboy.com/2020/01/28/braintree-integration-in-xamarin-forms-part-1/). I have integrated this in my Xamarin App but on IOS if i try to login using PayPal email and password its giving the below error

[image: PayPal Login Page]

[image: gives below message on screen]

On Android the PayPal Screen is not at all shown.

Do any of you have experience with Braintree or any other Payment gateway integration in Xamarin through which payment in PayPal can be done?
I have been looking for the PayPal mobile SDK, but no luck, so if you have hands-on experience, I would appreciate your advice.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a  list of supported payment options:

https://github.com/jimbobbennett/awesome-xamarin#payments

You can choose what you want